# Getting 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'attribute' exception with DRF

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, csrf

I've just changed to a new domain for my remote server, which was already serving JSON via Django Rest Framework (2.4.x).

Prior to the change, it smoothly authenticated users. However, after the switch, it's now throwing the error mentioned in the title.

Feels like a CSRF thing, but I don't know what to fix, or where to sleuth.

Pointers?

**Edit**:

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../project_path/project_name/urls.py", line 584, in list
related_field = self.request.user.relatedfield
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'relatedfield'
```

DRF Settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10,                 # Default to 10
    'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'page_size',  # Allow client to override, using `?page_size=xxx`.
    'MAX_PAGINATE_BY': 999             # Maximum limit allowed when using `?page_size=xxx`.
}
```

Comment: Please post the error traceback and DRF settings.

Comment: Just did that, please have a look!

Comment: Also, regular authentication (logging in, creating an account, etc.) works on the web page itself. It seems like this exception is only occurring in this particular DRF URL.

Comment: Has the user authenticated whenhe comes to this url? Also, please post your serializer and views where the above code is present.

Answer (score 1):

I think that since you are making requests from a different domain, the authentication is not able to work correctly.

Since you are using `SessionAuthentication`, it enforces the use of `CSRF token` and the whole purpose of CSRF check is to avoid  cross-site request forgeries.

Comment: It seems to have worked itself out after I updated the page forwarding rules on the old domain to (only) forward to the new domain. Before, it was also forwarding to https://, among other things. I have upvoted your answer and previous comments but I guess this can't count as an accepted answer. Thank you for your effort and help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This library help for cross site domain request [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers). cors-headers app will add `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers` to responses. Read the [`CORS`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors) mechanism.

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS: specify which non-standard HTTP headers can be used when making the actual request

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
        'x-requested-with',
        'content-type',
        'accept',
        'origin',
        'authorization',
        'x-csrftoken'
    )
```

Comment: Already am using CORS in the project. Thank you for the suggestion.